# Any way to produce a LaTeX table from an lme4 mer model fit object?

Tags: r, latex, lme4

Does anyone know a way to produce a nice publication quality LaTeX table from an lme4 `mer` object? Neither the `xtable` method (package `xtable`) nor the `latex` method (package `Hmisc`) know how to deal with `mer` objects.

For example, given this fit:

```
library(lme4)    
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Are there any options for producing a nice LaTeX table of the coefficient estimates for both the fixed and random effects?

EDIT:

Because this is somewhat buried in the comment threads below, note that a community wiki is in development for R LaTeX tables: [Tools for making latex tables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r)

Comment: xtable can take matrices and data frames as input. Why don't you just extract your quantities of interest from the model and feed them to xtable as a matrix? Alternatively, try apsrtable. It has a good extension system which makes it easy to add new models.

Comment: @ Vincent, thats typically what i do, and if doing it repeatedly, i write a function.

Comment: The tools on the wiki certainly work for fixed effects but not for random effects. Looking for answer to OP on the latter.

Comment: For HTML [tables](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/beautiful-table-outputs-summarizing-mixed-effects-models-rstats) and [plots](http://strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.lmer) check the [sjPlot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot) package.

Comment: Have you tried the stargazer package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a blog post that seems tailor made for this situation
[Latex Tables for lme4 Models](https://www.r-bloggers.com/code-latex-tables-for-lme4-models/)

Comment: +1 thx for the link. I was busy rewriting it myself, but apparently this has been done already.

Comment: @ Joris. There is a lot of excellent code out there on latex tables for different models, but I think they are spread far and wide. I have been thinking of posting a community wiki to gather all sources in one place, but don't think I have the necessary reputation points to do that. Do you think that would be something of interest to you?

Comment: @Joris, please start a community wiki, LaTeX tables are really a must.

Comment: @aL3xa : I made a community wiki here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r It's not a wiki yet, but it is flagged so soon a moderator should convert it to wiki. I need 10000 rep to do that, so I'm 320 short...

Comment: We want to build a knowledge base here, not just a link collection. Your answer would be better if you could extract the essence of the linked article in your answer.

Comment: This link is dead. Any replacements?

Answer (score 17):

The answer may be a bit late, but perhaps somebody may find it interesting:

```
library("texreg")
texreg(fm1)
```

To typeset multiple lme4 or other models side by side, use something like this:

```
texreg(list(fm1, fm2))
```

Answer (score 6):

I may have a hacky solution. I wanted the same thing, specifically the table of coefficients from a glmer model fit (the estimates, SEs, z, and p values).  Finding the right part of the summary output and feeding that into xtable seems to have done the trick.  Apologies for not supplying reproducible code & data, but from your original example:

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
xtable(summary(fm1)@coef)
```

Should give you the table of coefficients, SEs, etc. Note that it just gives the values, not the extra dressing-up of significance stars, etc.

Comment: `coef(summary(fm1))` is better than `summary(fm1)@coef` -- it should work in any version of `lme4`